# DOM Query How to get the first levels of matching?

Tags: dom, zend-framework2, zend-dom-query

I need to take all matches on first level depth
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.dom.query.html

It shows me all matches that contain class accordion + all child matches

```
$dom = new Query($html);
$results = $dom->execute('.accordion');
```

I'm getting all 6 nodes with class .accordion

Html

```
<div class="accordion">
    Test1
    <div class="accordion">
      Test2
        <div class="accordion">
            Test3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
    Name
    <div class="accordion">
      Name2
        <div class="accordion">
            Name3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**How Can I take only the first levels of DOM Objcets(Nodelist) without childs?**

It should be 
First object

```
<div class="accordion">
    Name
    <div class="accordion">
      Name2
        <div class="accordion">
            Name3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Second object

```
<div class="accordion">
    Name
    <div class="accordion">
      Name2
        <div class="accordion">
            Name3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you try using Xpath Notation using queryXpath method instead of execute method ?

Comment: I used notation..and it's still the same

Comment: //div[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' accordion-group ')][contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' exportable ')]

Comment: I've posted one more question,because I had't recived any answers using DOMXpath notation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839112/xpath-get-first-nodes

Comment: Well I suppose your div.accordion is in a specific container. Using "container > .accordion" selects direct children of a container.

Comment: What can be solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've tested some code

```
    $html = '
        <div class="container">
           <div class="accordion">
            Test1
            <div class="accordion">
              Test2
                <div class="accordion">
                    Test3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion">
            Name
            <div class="accordion">
              Name2
                <div class="accordion">
                    Name3
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    ';

   $dom = new \Zend\Dom\Query($html);
   // Will returns the first levels .accordion in .container ($results length is 2)
   $results = $dom->queryXpath('//div[@class="container"]/div[@class="accordion"]');
   echo '<pre>';
   foreach($results as $result){
       print_r($result);
   }
   exit;
```

echo :

```
DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => div
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => div
    [nodeValue] => 
                Test1

                  Test2

                        Test3



    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => div
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 
                Test1

                  Test2

                        Test3



)

DOMElement Object
(
    [tagName] => div
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => div
    [nodeValue] => 
                Name

                  Name2

                        Name3



    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => div
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => 
                Name

                  Name2

                        Name3



)
```